# Replace values in list

Tags: r

I have a nested list, which could look something like this:

```
characlist<-list(list(c(1,2,3,4)),c(1,3,2,NA))
```

Next, I want to replace all values equal to one with NA. I tried the following, but it produces an error:

```
lapply(characlist,function(x) ifelse(x==1,NA,x))

Error in ifelse(x == 1, NA, x) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `rapply` instead:

```
> rapply(characlist,function(x) ifelse(x==1,NA,x), how = "replace")
#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#[1] NA  2  3  4
#
#
#[[2]]
#[1] NA  3  2 NA
```

The problem in your initial approach was that your first list element is itself a list. Hence you cannot directly apply the `ifelse` logic as you would on an atomic vector. By using `?rapply` you can avoid that problem (`rapply` is a recursive version of `lapply`).

Answer (score 4):

Another option would be using `relist` after we `replace` the elements that are 1 to NA in the `unlist`ed vector.  We specify the `skeleton` as the original `list` to get the same structure.

```
 v1 <- unlist(characlist)
 relist(replace(v1, v1==1, NA), skeleton=characlist)
 #[[1]]
 #[[1]][[1]]
 #[1] NA  2  3  4


 #[[2]]
 #[1] NA  3  2 NA
```